# Динамический файл с переменными для python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Подскажите способ создания файла с переменными для кода на питоне который можно будет редактировать и сохранять в ходе действия кода. Я чет ваще не нашел никакой инфы, может руки уже искривились гуглить нормально.
К примеру, у меня есть чат-бот с фильтром запрещенных слов, он естественно эти запрещенный слова берет из списка, ну к примеру

```py
bad_words = [
    'редиска', 'картофель', 'баклажан'
]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for i in bad_words:
        if i in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
```

просто пример, так вот как можно сделать отдельный файл в котором будет этот список запрещенных слов `bad_words` чтобы и питон с ним хорошо работал и его можно было редактировать в ходе работы кода (добавить/удалить слова) и вместить в него прочие настройки которые будут динамичными.
Вручную редачить это же не вариант вовсе а сохранять все в оперативной памяти которая очищается после закрытия кода это...

Comment: Может, `SQLite` база данных? Она хранится как файл, то есть её можно очень просто переносить вместе с кодом. Так же в `Python` есть стандартные библиотеки для работы с ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно использовать файл в формате JSON:

Код:

```py
import json

# ... там, где это нужно
with open('bad_words.json', 'r') as f:
    bad_words = json.loads(f.read())
```

Файл:

```
["редиска", "картофель", "баклажан"]
```

Но учтите, что по стандарту JSON в файле кавычки должны быть двойными, а в конце списка не должно быть запятой. Если хочется больше вольности, то можно использовать [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), который парсит питоновские значения:

```py
# ... там, где это нужно
with open('bad_words.data', 'r') as f:
    bad_words = eval(f.read())
```

Файл в таком случае может быть более свободного формата, но учтите, что это не JSON:

```py
["редиска", 'картофель', 'баклажан', ]
```